# Multiplicación directa en PHP con valores del input

Tags: php

Buenas tardes colegas,

Necesito de su ayuda deseo generar el total de una compra (los valores son traidos de la base de datos) tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
                                $consulta = "select  pro.nombre, pro.costo,pro.cantidad                          
                                    from factura f inner join cliente c on f.idcliente = c.idcliente inner join pedido p 
                                    on p.idcliente = c.idcliente inner join menu m on m.idmenu = p.idmenu inner join categoria cat on cat.idmenu = m.idmenu
                                inner join producto pro on pro.id = cat.id inner join mesa me on me.idmesa = m.idmesa
                                where c.idcliente = $id and p.estado='D'";
                                $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
                                ?>
                                        <thead>
                                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                                        <th>Detalle</th>
                                        <th>Valor Unitario</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <?php while ($pedidos = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><?php echo"{$pedidos["cantidad"]}" ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo"{$pedidos["nombre"]}" ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo"{$pedidos["costo"]}" ?></td>
                                                <td>aqui va el resultado de cantidad * costo</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias hacer algo asi:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$row['producto']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['cantidad']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['precio']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['cantidad'] * $row['precio']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "sin productos";
}
```

espero te sirva..!!